# Limit counter of products

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have counter of products in my app.

I want to make limit of products - 0

Now if i have 0 and tap "minus" it shows "-1"

I want to limit it on "0"

```
        plus.Click += delegate
        {
            counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count);
        };  
        minus.Click += delegate
        {
            counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", --count);
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try create a rule using a [ternay operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx), for sample;

```
    plus.Click += delegate
    {
        counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count);
    };  
    minus.Click += delegate
    {
        counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", count > 0 ? --count : 0);
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
plus.Click += delegate
{
    counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", ++count);
};  
minus.Click += delegate
{
    counttext.Text = string.Format("{0}", count > 0 ? --count : 0);
};
```

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to mark the answer that solve your problem so others can easily find the solution.